# Regexp to check continuous 3 digits in a string

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression in java to check, if a string contains continuous 3 digits. But the problem is my string may contain unicode characters. If the string contains unicode characters it should skip the unicode characters (skip 4 '.'s after & AND #) and should do the checking. Some examples are

```
Neeraj : false
Neeraj123 : true
&#1234Neeraj : false
&#1234Neeraj123 : true
123N&#123D : true
Neeraj&#1234 : false
Neeraj&#12DB123 : true
&#1234 : false
```

Comment: @pst: I don't agree it's that trivial. You'd need to know about lookarounds to be able to come up with a concept for a solution. And he did provide a comprehensive test suite which does show some effort.

Comment: @pst: OK, I'll gladly upvote a regex solution that doesn't need lookaround (and remains readable).

Comment: tht was a way to difficult problem..although it looks simple :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a negative [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(?<!             # Make sure there is no...           \n" +
    " &\\#            # &#, followed by                    \n" +
    " [0-9A-F]{0,3}   # zero to three hex digits           \n" +
    ")                # right before the current position. \n" +
    "\\d{3}           # Only then match three digits.", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

You can use it as follows:

```
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
return regexMatcher.find();  // returns True if regex matches, else False
```

Comment: With `String.matches(String regex)`, this returns false for all the examples.

Comment: @BheshGurung: Well, yes. `matches()` is the wrong tool for this. It expects the regex to match the entire string. Neeraj is asking about how to *search* in the string for three digits that aren't part of a Unicode escape sequence. That's what the `find()` method is for. Use the right tool for the job...

Comment: I didn't read the question clearly. By bad. In that case this works perfect. +1. I wonder whY the OP hasn't accepted the answer yet. :)

Comment: @BheshGurung: I must admit that I'm confused by the question myself. The title says *find*, the contents say *check*...so I guess your point is valid. But in the end, it's Java's fault for using such a confusing method name. :)

Comment: @Tim: as BheshGurung said, I want to match against the criteria mentioned and want to know if the string matches the criteria mentioned and it returns true or false ... It was my mistake that I wrote find in the title and check in the content body. It should be check everywhere. Apologies for that .. I am correcting it.

Comment: @BheshGurung Can I use like this?    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
       return true;
   } else
   return false

Comment: @Neeraj: Don't do that. Use `return regexMatcher.find();`. No need for `if`.

Comment: @Tim But My input is a single word and i want to return true or false if the string matches your regex.

Comment: @Neeraj: Yes, that's exactly what `return regexMatcher.find();` will do. `.find()` already returns a Boolean!

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ok I got it. My previous comment was a foolish one :)

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker. It is working perfectly in my application

Comment: @wvxvw: It may be that Java is more lenient than other regex flavors, but many do require the 0. JavaScript, for example, will treat `a{,3}` as "match `a`, then `{`, then `3`, then `}`". Better be safe than sorry.