# Regular expression find if same character repeats 3 or more no of times in Java

Tags: java, regex

My requirement is to use only **Java** regular expression to check if a given string contains the same character repeated more than 3 times in continuation within the string.

**For ex :**

```
"hello"  -> false
"ohhhhh" -> true
"whatsuppp" -> true
```

Comment: The same question in php is not down voted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206983/regexp-to-check-continuous-3-digits-in-a-string

Comment: There are slight differences in ways of the same regex work in different languages. The link in above comment proves it.

If someone down vote anything, there should be pointed reason, IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp to check continuous 3 digits in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206983/regexp-to-check-continuous-3-digits-in-a-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following regex for your problem:

```
^.*(.)\1\1.*$
```

**Explanation**

1. `^` starting point of your string
2. `.*` any char 0 to N times
3. `(.)` one char in the capturing group that will be used by the backreference
4. `\1` back reference to the captured character (we call it twice to force your 3 times repetition constraint)
5. `.*` any char 0 to N times
6. `$` end of the input string

I have tested on :

```
hello -> false
ohhhhh -> true
whatsuppp -> true
aaa -> true
aaahhhahj -> true
abcdef -> false
abceeedef -> true
```

Last but not least, you have to add a backslash `\` before each backslash `\` in your regex before being able to use it in your Java code.

This give you the following prototype Java code:

```
  ArrayList <String> strVector = new ArrayList<String>();
  strVector.add("hello");
  strVector.add("ohhhhh");
  strVector.add("whatsuppp");
  strVector.add("aaa");
  strVector.add("aaahhhahj");
  strVector.add("abcdef");
  strVector.add("abceeedef");

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(.)\\1\\1.*$");
  Matcher matcher;        

  for(String elem:strVector)
  {
    System.out.println(elem);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(elem);
    if (matcher.find())System.out.println("Found you!");
    else System.out.println("Not Found!");
  }
```

giving at execution the following output:

```
hello
Not Found!
ohhhhh
Found you!
whatsuppp
Found you!
aaa
Found you!
aaahhhahj
Found you!
abcdef
Not Found!
abceeedef
Found you!
```

Comment: For those who want to detect if same number repeats 3 or more use the regex: `^[0-9]*([0-9])\1\1[0-9]*$`